# UTF-8 strings in a MySQL database got messed up after configuration change

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a MySQL with strings that I left dormant for a while. Now that I picked it up again, I noticed that all the special characters are screwed up. My ISP has ported the server to a different machine, I suspect that this might be when it happened.

The database was populated by a PHP script. Everything was supposed to be in UTF-8, that's what the database is set to.

However, this is what a string looks like now:

`fÃƒÂªte`

Those four special characters are supposed to be one character, `ê`, the string is meant to be `fête`.

Now it looks like this is just re-encoded twice, but that doesn't seem right. Those four characters in hex are:

`C3 83 C6 92 C3 82 C2 AA`

This looks very much like UTF-8, so if we decode it, we get

`C3 3F C2 AA`

This isn't quite UTF-8 (because of the `3F`), but let's decode it again:

`FF AA`

This is not UTF-8.

The `ê` character is `EA`, in UTF-8, that would be `C3 AA`.

Another example: The Spanish upside-down question mark (`¿`) is there as `C8 83 E2 80 9A C3 82 C2`, which decodes to `C3 3F 82 BF`, which isn't proper UTF-8 again (translates to `FF 82 BF`). The expected character for `¿` is `BF`, i.e. `C2 BF` in proper UTF-8.

What happened here? How did the characters get messed up? More importantly, how do I fix it?

(Side note - the new server requires me to write `mysql_set_charset("utf8");` or else strings get messed up too, although in the "UTF-8 as latin1" fashion, not in this weird fashion as seen above.)

TL;DR:

- MySQL database was populated in UTF-8 through PHP script
- Lay dormant for years, server got migrated.
- Now characters are messed up, see above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
C3 83 C6 92 C3 82 C2 AA
```

> This looks very much like UTF-8, so if we decode it, we get

```
C3 3F C2 AA
```

That's what you get if you treat the sequence of bytes as UTF-8, then encode it as ISO-8859-1. `3F` is `?`, which has been included as a replacement character, because UTF-8 `C6 92` is U+0192 `ƒ` which does not exist in ISO-8859-1. But it does exist in Windows code page 1252 Western European, an encoding very similar to ISO-8859-1; there, it's byte 0x83.

```
C3 83 C2 AA
```

Go through another round of treat-as-UTF-8-bytes-and-encode-to-cp1252 and you get:

```
C3 AA
```

which is, finally, UTF-8 for `ê`.

Note that even if you serve a non-XML HTML page explicitly as ISO-8859-1, browsers will actually use the cp1252 encoding, due to nasty historical reasons.

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have a cp1252 encoding; `latin1` is (correctly) ISO-8859-1. So you won't be able to fix up the data by dumping as latin1 then reloading as utf8 (twice). You'd have to process the script with a text editor that can save as either (or eg in Python `file(path, 'rb').read().decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8').encode('cp1252')`).

Comment: +1, was looking for the charset but didn't thought of CP-1252.

Comment: Answers like this make me regret you can only upvote once. Awesome work, bobster, you missed your calling as a master detective! I'll give this a shot.

Comment: ...aaaaaand it worked! In PHP, I'm basically just calling `mb_convert_encoding($String, "CP1252", "UTF-8")` twice. I would have NEVER expected the Spanish Inquisition (or Codepage 1252, for that matter). You're a genius.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! I was in Perl, and here's what i ended up with:

    `perl -e 'use Encode; my $f; {undef $/; $f=<STDIN>;}
      $f=decode("UTF-8", $f);
      $f=encode("cp1252", $f);
      $f=decode("UTF-8", $f);
      binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"); print $f;' < bad.dump > good.dump`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you might have your characters stored as UTF8 strings in a latin1 (or similar) database. That's why you've got 'double encoding' problem. Making the database's CHARSET UTF8 should fix it. Dumping/importing the data might be necessary as well, something along those lines:

```
$ mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1  --skip-set-charset --databases xxx > xxx.sql
$ mysql --default-character-set=utf8 < xxx.sql
```

But that's just suggestion, might work but don't have to in your specific case.

Comment: The table is set to UTF-8, but I'll still give it a shot.

Comment: The database CHARSET should be UTF8 as well.

Comment: Good point. I checked, and it is. Also, the connection collation is utf8_unicode_ci.

Comment: Wait - the column is utf8_general_ci, but the table's collation is latin1_swedish_ci.

Comment: Collation doesn't matter. Anyway, you should just try to dump your database using different combinations of -default-character-set and check in your editor if your utf8 strings are fine. If they are you should use this file to restore the database properly.

Comment: +1 from me, although I think bobince with his Sherlock Holmes impression wins this round.