# Decode unknow charset text save by php

Tags: java, php, character-encoding

I have a some record in MySQL such as

```
Váº­n hÃ nh linh hoáº¡t trong má»i Ä‘k giao thÃ´ng
```

which in hex as

> 56 c3 a1 c2 ba c2 ad 6e 20 68 c3 83 c2 a0 6e 68 20 6c 69 6e 68 20 68
>   6f c3 a1 c2 ba c2 a1 74 20 74 72 6f 6e 67 20 6d c3 a1 c2 bb c2 8d 69
>   20 c3 84 e2 80 98 6b 20 67 69 61 6f 20 74 68 c3 83 c2 b4 6e 67 20

[image: hex dump]

I dont know how PHP save it, but read it from Java MySQL Connector show some strange character. And I can make it show the origin text by

```
copy the text above --> Notepad++ - Encoding in ASCII --> Paste text
--> Encoding in UTF-8
```

the original text should be:

```
Vận hành linh hoạt trong mọi đk giao thông
```

I know the problem is PHP save incorrect text format, but is there a way to decode it correctly in Java?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019117/does-jdbc-support-persian-language).

Comment: Here [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8)

Comment: @brettw @XtraCode: yep, I've already tried some thing like: `new String(res.getBytes(),"UTF-8")` without success. The most similar topic I found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861803/utf-8-strings-in-a-mysql-database-got-messed-up-after-configuration-change , but I still cannot make it work in Python and Java.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the hex is *exactly* correct?  Here is what I did...

```
String MESS = "56 c3 a1 c2 ba c2 ad 6e 20 68 c3 83 c2 a0 6e 68 20 6c 69 6e 68 20 68 6f c3 a1 c2 ba c2 a1 74 20 74 72 6f 6e 67 20 6d c3 a1 c2 bb c2 8d 69 20 c3 84 e2 80 98 6b 20 67 69 61 6f 20 74 68 c3 83 c2 b4 6e 67 20";
String[] hexchars = MESS.split(" ");
byte[] buf = new byte[hexchars.length];
for (int i = 0; i < hexchars.length; i++) {
    buf[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hexchars[i], 16);
}

try {
    String s1 = new String(buf, "UTF-8");  // First encode UTF-8
    buf = s1.getBytes("cp1252");           // ...then translate to cp1252
    s1 = new String(buf, "UTF-8");         // ...then back to UTF-8
    System.out.println(s1);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the printed result is:

Vận hành linh hoạt trong m�?i đk giao thông

Which is *almost* right.  Except the decoding of mọi it is incorrect, which makes me suspect the hex that you provided may not be correct.  If you are 100% sure it is correct, I can try a little more to decode it.

UPDATE:
Here are my further thoughts:

- You need to find out what encoding MySQL itself (the database) is set to.
- You need to find out what encoding PHP is set to

  - possibly in PHP.INI
  - possibly set in the HTML metadata for the page that populates the table.
- You need to find out what if any encoding the PHP MySQL driver runs with

Only then will there be a possibility of setting the MySQL Connector/J to the right encoding, and then possibly applying a second conversion in Java.

Comment: yep, I've attach the hexdump from Navicat-Mysql, it's look the hex was correct.

Comment: Does the PHP code also read the data back correctly?  Or does it only insert data and never reads it?

Comment: yes, PHP read it correctly(notice: the sequence I work on Notepad++ to get the original text - from the question).